A curious equality from the book of A Blanchard which leads to $\liminf \frac{\pi(x,4,1)\log(x)}{x}\geq\frac{3a}{10}$, so infinitude of primes =1 mod4
In the first chapter of the Book(French), Initiation à la théorie analytique des nombres premiers(Blanchard, Dunod 1969), I am only stuck on one equation that leads to $$\liminf_{ x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\pi(x,4,1)\log(x)}{x} \geq \frac{3a}{10}$$ where: $$\pi(x,4,1)=\sum_{\substack{p\leq x \newline \text{p prime}\newline p \equiv 1 \mod 4}}1$$ and a is the famous constant used in Chebyshev's proof of the Bertrand postulate: $$a=\log(2^{\frac{1}{2}}3^{\frac{1}{3}}5^{\frac{1}{5}}30^{-\frac{1}{30}})=0,9212...$$
Let's:
$$\chi_4(n):=\begin{cases}0 & \mbox{ if  } n\equiv 0 \mod 4\newline 1 & \mbox{ if } n\equiv 1 \mod 4\newline -1 & \mbox{ if } n\equiv 3 \mod 4\end{cases}
$$
and
$$\psi(x_4,\chi):=\sum_{n \leq x} \chi_4(n)\Lambda(n)
$$
Where $\Lambda$ is the Von Mangoldt function. Then is it true that:
$$\sum_{n\leq x} \chi_4(n) \log(n) =\sum_{n\leq x} \chi_4(n) \psi\left(\frac{x}{n},\chi_4\right) 
$$
I tried to follow the same method to prove that $$\sum_{n\leq x}\log(n) =\sum_{n\leq x}  \psi\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$
but I am stuck.

It seems that $$\sum_{n\leq x} \chi_6(n) \log(n) =\sum_{n\leq x} \chi_6(n) \psi\left(\frac{x}{n},\chi_6\right) 
$$ also work with:
$$\chi_6(n):=\begin{cases}0 & \mbox{ if  } n\equiv 0,2,4 \mod 6\newline 1 & \mbox{ if } n\equiv 1 \mod 6\newline -1 & \mbox{ if } n\equiv 5 \mod 6\end{cases}
$$
